# NullPointerException in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the following code. The main aim of the code is to take an input from the user in one class, and pass it to another class for constructing a `GridLayout`.

Here is the code for my first class...

```
public class A{
    int N;
    JLabel label;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField text;

    public A(){
        frame=new JFrame();
        panel=new JPanel();
        text=new JTextField(20);
        label=new JLabel("Enter the number of states");
        button=new JButton("Submit");

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                N=Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
                B1 page=new B1(N);
                page.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(320,240);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        A ab=new A();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my second class...

```
public class B1 extends A {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel pan;
    JButton button;
    double transition[][];
    JTextField tf[][];

    B1(int N){
        this.N=N;
        frame=new JFrame("Transition matrix");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pan=new JPanel();
        pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(N+1,N));

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
                tf[i][j]=new JTextField();
                pan.add(tf[i][j]);
            }
        }

        button=new JButton("Submit");
        pan.add(button);
        frame.add(pan);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Print and read the stack trace.  It tells you exactly which .java source file and line number where the NPE was thrown.  That should be enough to figure out what you did wrong.  You failed to initialize a reference before you used it.

Comment: `tf[][]` in `B1` is not initialized

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 4):

In the constructor of `B1` class, you need to `new` your `JTextField` array(`tf`) like:

```
...    
tf = new JTextField[N][N];
//code start
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        tf[i][j]=new JTextField();
        pan.add(tf[i][j]);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That helped. And I was trying out all possible combinations with GridLayout thinking that was where the problem was. Thank you!